# How to concatenate values using Reactive Forms?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to concatenate 2 values into 1 label using Reactive Forms.
In this case i'm not using ngModel binding.

```
 <label 
                     id="identificationCode"
                     name="identificationCode"
                     formControlName="lblIdCode">______</label>

<input type="text" 
                        id="reference"
                        name="reference"
                        formControlName="txtReference"
                        maxlength="250"
                        (change)="handleIdCode($event)">

<input type="text" 
                        id="publicacion"
                        name="publicacion"
                        formControlName="txtPublicacion"
                        maxlength="250"
                        (change)="handleIdCode($event)">
```

I want to concatenate those 2 input text when user is writing and automatically reflect the value into the label.  Is there any way like we do it with model binding without ***change event***??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is that you can use reference variables to refer to controls within the template. Like so

```
<label 
 id="identificationCode"
 name="identificationCode">{{reference.value + " - " + publicacion.value}}</label>

<input type="text" 
 id="reference"
 name="reference"
 formControlName="txtReference"
 maxlength="250"
 #reference>

<input type="text" 
 id="publicacion"
 name="publicacion"
 formControlName="txtPublicacion"
 maxlength="250"
 #publicacion>
```

The important parts are the `#reference` and `#publicacion` on each of the inputs. This links the controls to the variables.

You can then use these variables within an Angular interpolation block like `{{reference.value + " - " + publicacion.value}}`. You can combine the values however you want inside this block.

Answer (score 2):

Use label to display the information. The label is not meant to bind with Reactive Form. If you need concatenate values to pass to API or for any use then try on TS. User cannot change the value of Label so there is no point to bind it, but just display the concatenated value.

Remove `formControlName="lblIdCode"` from your label and add `for` attribute.

```
<label>{{form.get('txtReference').value}} - {{form.get('txtPublicacion').value}}</label>
```

And concatenate on TS:

```
const lblIdCode = this.form.get('txtReference').value + this.form.get('txtPublicacion').value
```

**The definition of label:**

The HTML  element represents a caption for an item in a user interface.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 1):

Although given answers work fine. There could be another declarative approach which will take advantage of `valueChanges` observables of the input text. We can combine the input texts' `valuechanges` observables and map to the desired output i.e. concatenate the `Reference + Publicacion` like this:

**Component.ts:**

```
export class FormreactiveComponent implements OnInit {
  lblIdCode$: Observable<string>;

  form = new FormGroup({
    txtReference: new FormControl(''),
    txtPublicacion: new FormControl('')    
   });

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const refCtrl = this.form.get('txtReference');
    const pubCtrl = this.form.get('txtPublicacion');

    this.lblIdCode$ = combineLatest(refCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(refCtrl.value)), 
                                   pubCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(pubCtrl.value)))
                      .pipe(map(([firstName, lastName]) => {
                        return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
                      }));
  }    
}
```

**Template:**

```
<form name="form" [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtReference">Reference</label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" formControlName="txtReference"/>            
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtPublicacion">Publicacion</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="txtPublicacion"/>            
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblIdCode">{{lblIdCode$ | async}}</label>             
      </div>          
</form>
```

[Working example](http://%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-hnwbsn?file=src/app/formreactive/formreactive.component.html)

Comment:  ,you are completely correct I like the reactive thinking but it 's look like we need to set form control lblIdCode this what I got from the answer not just concat  , this just assimtion in both case you answer goal  work well 

Answer (score 0):

Try using the form values, just like you'd use in the .ts file.

```
<label 
     id="identificationCode"
     name="identificationCode"
     formControlName="lblIdCode">
     {{form.value.reference + ' ' + form.value.publicacion}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a get property base of these values like in

componenpe ts

```
get referencePublicacionValues() : string {
 return `${this.form.get(txtReference).value} ${this.form.get('txtPublicacion').value}`
}
```

*template*

```
<label 
     id="identificationCode"
     name="identificationCode">
     {{referencePublicacionValues}}
</label>
```

now you have the value in reference Publicacion Values property any change the value will reflect to the ui

> you can't use formControlName directive on labels if you want to set
>   the formcontrol `lblIdCode` you can use **form valueChanges**

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe( () => {
 this.form.get('lblIdCode').setValue(this.referencePublicacionValues,{emitEvent: false})
})
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ractive-form-without-form-tag-hherdu)